# SQL UNIQUE operator giving error when used in nested query

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

I have 3 tables- `Sailors`,`Reserves`and`Boats`. But when I use the `UNIQUE` operator in the following manner, I get an error

> Error at line 3:  ORA-00936: missing expression

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Sailors S
WHERE UNIQUE (SELECT R.bid
FROM Reserves R
WHERE R.bid=103 AND S.sid=R.sid)
```

Comment: Isn't `unique`just a synonym for `distinct` used in older Oracle SQL? What is it you want the query to do?

Comment: you need to use select unique s.sname

Comment: Hi @Rajesh I knew about UNIQUE..just wanted to try alternatives..not sure why that's not working

Comment: @jpw Oh ok..I didn't know that Distinct has been deprecated

Comment: @SagarKalburgi, try this SELECT S.sname
FROM Sailors S
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT R.bid
FROM Reserves R
WHERE R.bid=103 AND S.sid=R.sid)

Comment: @SagarKalburgi it's the other way around; distinct is ANSI standard and unique is the old oracle specific. If it has been deprecated I don't know. I guess my comment was a bit vague.

Comment: I think WHERE UNIQUE (subquery) is not valid syntax. You want to check that the subquery produces only one row?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `EXISTS` similar to your approach

```
SELECT UNIQUE  S.sname 
FROM Sailors S 
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT R.bid 
        FROM Reserves R 
        WHERE R.bid=103 AND S.sid=R.sid)
```